# Combinatorial - Ways to create subcommittees of a certain size out of a committee?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Each member of a 10 member committee must be assigned to exactly one of 3 subcommittees (management, supervisor, employee). If these subcommittees are to contain 1,3, and 6 members respectively, how many different subcommittees can be appointed?

I solved this by doing this:

c(10,1) for management, c(9,3) for supervisor, c(6,6) for employees.

c(10,1) * c(9,3) * c(6,6) = different ways to arrange subcommittees. Is this correct? If not, what did I do wrong and what's a better way?

Comment: That's fine. You should find that it simplifies to $\frac{10!}{6!3!1!}$. (You can interpret this as "arrange the 10 people in any order; the first 6 (in any order) will form one committee, the next three (in any order) will form one committee, and the next one (in any order) will form one committee". This is called a *multinomial coefficient*.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, indeed, your answer is correct. There is in fact a simpler way to approach this sort of problem: through the use of [multinomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient) (see the two rightmost terms below):

$$\binom{10}{1}\cdot\binom{9}{3} \cdot\binom 66 =\dfrac {10!}{\require{cancel}1!\cdot\color{blue}{\cancel{ 9!}}} \cdot \dfrac {\color{blue}{\cancel{9!}}}{\color{blue}{\cancel{6!}}\cdot 3!}\cdot \dfrac{\color{blue}{\cancel{6!}}}{6!} = \dfrac{10!}{1!\cdot 3!\cdot 6!} = \binom{10}{1, 3, 6}$$

Notice the nice cancellations in the factorials above! Do take a moment to read over the linked entry in Wikipedia: *multinomial coefficients.* Multinomial coefficients are perfectly suited to just this sort of problem, and simply save *you* some calculations.

Comment: amy, you might appreciate my post [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8847/12952) if you haven't already seen it.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, that's right.  There's a few ways of doing it, all equivalent.

$\text{Y}{\small \text{OUR}}\text{ W}{\small \text{AY}}$: $${10 \choose 1}{9 \choose 3} = \frac{10!}{1!(10-1)!}\frac{9!}{3!(9-3)!} =840$$ There are $10$ choices for the manager.  After you pick him, there's only nine choices left for the three supervisors, and after that everybody else is an employee.

$\text{M}{\small \text{Y}}\text{ W}{\small \text{AY}}$:
$${10 \choose 6}{4 \choose 1}=\frac{10!}{6!(10-6)!}\frac{4!}{1!(4-1)!} =840$$
It's similar to the above: first pick the employees, then the manager.

Can you think of a third way?

**Moreover, can you generalize** by finding a formula to count the ways to choose any number of subcommittees (of whichever sizes) from $n$ people?  (*Hint:* does anything cancel in the above formulas?)

Comment: I do see a general way to do this, but can't seem to put it into a formula.

Comment: Woops, pressed enter for a line break and it posted the comment. Something like (n / #group1! * #group2! * group3!)...

Comment: exactly, user56763! See the expansion of the multinomia coefficient: numerator is $n!$, denominator is the factorials of each subgroup size!

Comment: @user56763 $$\require{cancel}\frac{n!}{k_1!\cancel{(n-k_1)!}}\frac{\cancel{(n-k_1)!}}{k_2!(n-k_2)!}\cdots = \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots}$$ Note that if one insists that *all* $n$ people be distributed between the committees, $k_1+k_2+\cdots = n$, so the final step leaves only the $k$'s in the denominator.