# Combinations exercises

Tags: combinatorics

I got 2 combination excercises that i'm stuck on.

I would be forever grateful for some help on these 2.

1) In a group of 40 people we wish to form 2 teams:

Soccer and basketball, to play Soccer we need 11 players and 7 spare players ( 18 people) and to play Basketball we need 5 players and 7 spare players(  12 players )

In how many ways can we create  the 2 teams with the 40 people if one person can only be at one team at a time?

2) In a group of 20 actors,  we require 2 groups of 6 people to make 2  plays.

In how many ways can we pick the 2 groups if no actor can be in both the 2 plays?

My guess is  $  40 C 18 * 22 C 12 + 40 C 12 * 28 C 18$ for the first one, but i'm not sure and for the second one my guess would be: $ (20 C 6 *14 C 6)*2 $

Comment: You will be more likely to get help if you describe where you are stuck and what you have tried.

Comment: You're so right, forgot to add what I came up with :D Just edited it

Answer (score 1):

At least for the first one, I suggest thinking of the problem as coming up with *three* groups; the people on the basketball team, the ones on the soccer team, an the ones on neither team.

This is by analogy to the simpler situation when you just want (say) a basketball team of five players out of twelve people, you are really lining everyone up in order ($12!$), having a cutoff after five people and before the last seven, and then dividing by the number of ways to reorder the five *and* the seven - hence $\frac{12!}{5!7!}=\binom{12}{5}=12C5$.

The second one is a little trickier because the two groups are the same size, but if you look at it as picking the people for play 1, play 2, and neither play, it should be clearer.

(Second hint: [multinomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448365/combinatorial-ways-to-create-subcommittees-of-a-certain-size-out-of-a-committe).)